# How to import Bootstrap 5 RTL into Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel-8, bootstrap-5

I know that we can import bootstrap 5 into laravel so

scss/app.scss

```php
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

resource/bootstrap.js

```php
import "bootstrap";
```

app.blade

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

I want to import the `bootstrap RTL` from `node_modules` so i can change the default theme ..

but there is no `bootstrap.rtl.scss`
just `bootstrap.rtl.css` in `dist` folder

I tried

_variables.scss

```php
$body-bg: rgb(190, 20, 182);
```

app.scss

```php
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "variables"; // here is my won variables
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

app.blade

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css') }}">
```

But the background did not change

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the documented order of scss libraries on the bootstrap site does not necessarily work.  I got the background to change using the following order in app.scss, and including the main bootstrap.scss file.  The RTL documentation claims the following:

"When it comes to customization, the preferred way is to take advantage of variables, maps, and mixins. This approach works the same for RTL, **even if it’s post-processed from the compiled files**, thanks to how RTLCSS works."

So that's why I included the RTL dist css in the app.scss as well.

Using the following in app.scss:

```
@import "_variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"
```

And putting the following in the webpack.mix.js file to compile:

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

And then this in your app.blade to pull in the compiled js and css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
<script type="text" src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

This method required installing bootstrap, @popperjs/core, sass, sass-loader, and resolve-url-loader using npm, and running

```
npm run watch
```

to compile and play around with it.